# "pip install scipy" failed in Travis CI python 3.7 env

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, travis-ci

I have problem to setup my project in Travis CI python 3.7 environment, although simply running with 'pip install scipy' in python 3.6 works fine. There lots of similar/same problems and solutions reported before [1], but answers does not work for me.

Can anyone help to explain why it works with python 3.6 [2], while failed with python 3.7 in Travis CI server ?

I finally tried with the following scripts, but it still does not work in Travis CI (python 3.7) env. Travis CI (python 3.6 and python 3.6 dev) still work fine.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
sudo apt-get build-dep python-scipy
sudo apt-get install -qq python-scipy
pip install scipy
...
```

[1] https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2890

[2] https://travis-ci.org/jerrygaoLondon/jgtextrank/jobs/323822420

Errors:

`Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy ... error
  Complete output from command /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7-dev/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-j7d10poq/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp2u1cz0lipip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7-dev/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE
...`

For more details of the error, please check out https://travis-ci.org/jerrygaoLondon/jgtextrank/jobs/323822422

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no binary wheels yet for Python 3.7 (the list is on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy) so pip downloads the source package for SciPy and attempts to compile it. This fails most of the time because you need a full development environment for Python and the assorted libraries (BLAS and LAPACK with development headers), see https://scipy.org/install.html and https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/INSTALL.rst.txt .

Your solutions:

1. Roll back to Python 3.6, which I would suggest.
2. Make sure to install the development libraries for Python 3.7 and the libraries (+ headers) for BLAS and LAPACK.

Comment: For those on on Windows, you can use [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy](Chris Gohlke's binary); It works for 3.7 and Scipy. You might need to use his numpy+mkl binary to get this to work, even though numpy will probably compile/install through pip with 3.7 on its own.